# How to send form containing files via jQuery ajax using PATCH method to Laravel 5?

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, laravel, patch

This is my code:

```
 //routes.php
Route::match(['post', 'patch'],'/slide/{id}', function() {
    dd(request()->all());
});

//form
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <input type="file" name="image">
</form>

//js
$('#form').on('submit',(function(e) {

    $.ajax({

        type: "PATCH",
        url:'/slide/' + id,
        data: new FormData(this),
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false

    }).done(function(r) {

        console.log(r);

    });
}));
```

When I use POST method everything is fine and dd(request()->all()) returns:

```
array:2 [
  "title" => "foo"
  "file" => UploadedFile {#400
    -test: false
    -originalName: "bar.png"
    -mimeType: "image/png"
    -size: 4413
    -error: 0
    ...
  }
]
```

but when change method to PATCH i receive empty array.

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong and share proper way of sending FormData via ajax using PATCH method to L5?

Im using Laravel 5.2 and jQuery 2.2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this named **method spoofing**. this trick is what Laravel does in its forms.
if you want to send patch request you can put this line in your code.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

you can read more about [method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#form-method-spoofing) here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it does the trick but i think it is not proper solution

Comment: It's the standard non-ajax way of doing it with Laravel. Believe me, it is proper.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue while sending a form using AJAX. I used the `formData.append()` function to add the `_method` field to the `FormData()` before sending.

In your code it would look like this:

```
$('#form').on('submit',(function(e) {
  var formData = new FormData(this);

  formData.append('_method', 'patch');  
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:'/slide/' + id,
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  }).done(function(r) {
  console.log(r);
});
```

Comment: It's weird. I always use ajax with `type: 'PATCH'` without any problems, Why this is happening when uploading files only?

Answer (score 0):

The solution with the hidden input is the correct one. The docs explain this nicely.

But another problem is, that the `$request` array is not available in its calling context. Laravel will recognize this parameter and pass it to your `Closure` in the following:

```
Route::match(['post', 'patch'],'/slide/{id}', function($request) {
  dd(request()->all());
});
```