# Unable to acess form data which is sent through ajax patch request

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, patch

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/inventories/'+inventoryJavaScriptData.id, 
    type: 'PATCH', 
    data: data, 
    contentType: false, 
    cache: false, 
    processData: false, 
    success: (response) => { 
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status == 'true') {

        }else{

        }
    },
    error: (errorResponse)=>{
        $.notify('error! please try again' , 'error'  );
    }
})
```

Comment: set `contentType` to `application/json` instead of `false` also no need for `cache` and `processData` unless you are trying to upload a file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send form containing files via jQuery ajax using PATCH method to Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127289/how-to-send-form-containing-files-via-jquery-ajax-using-patch-method-to-laravel)

Comment: Set request type to POST and add `_method` parameter with value `PATCH` to your POST data. Web browsers can't make PATCH requests. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing